# Gnome password dialog not showing up

Tags: linux, ssh, gnome, filezilla, wayland

I have a HP Probook 4545s notebook with a some weeks old Arch Linux installation. Most of the time when I want to use Filezilla or SSH, the Gnome password dialog does not appear to ask for the SSH key password. So then I can't use Filezilla or SSH.

I tried both a Gnome session and a Wayland session. In the Gnome session it sometimes works, and in the Wayland session it never does. I can't figure out what is the problem here.

I have found some log entries ( `journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon` ) :

```
    -- Reboot --
Okt 02 17:21:40 hannes-laptop gnome-keyring-daemon[814]: couldn't register in session: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .serv
Okt 02 17:27:07 hannes-laptop gnome-keyring-daemon[1247]: another secret service is running
-- Reboot --
Okt 02 21:02:15 hannes-laptop gnome-keyring-daemon[840]: couldn't allocate secure memory to keep passwords and or keys from being written to the disk
-- Reboot --
Okt 03 07:22:34 hannes-laptop gnome-keyring-daemon[821]: couldn't register in session: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .serv
Okt 03 07:27:27 hannes-laptop gnome-keyring-daemon[1721]: couldn't register in session: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .ser
Okt 03 07:27:27 hannes-laptop gnome-keyring-daemon[1721]: another secret service is running
Okt 03 07:43:52 hannes-laptop gnome-keyring-daemon[2769]: couldn't register in session: Unable to register client
Okt 03 07:43:52 hannes-laptop gnome-keyring-daemon[2769]: another secret service is running
```

Comment: It is terribly difficult to diagnose something with no error messages. Linux provides a directory with most log files (not all!) in /var/log. You might start by sifting thru those files searching for a relevant entry.